# How to ignore ' symbol when returning from MVC. document.insertAdjacent

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I return some code in MVC project to a web page. And i could not solve the problem with Apostrophe, how do i ignore it when my call look like this

```
document.getElementById('some').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','L'apostrophe');
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the string with backslash `\'` or use another quotes `"` or ` backtick

Comment: Had to change a lot of my " quotes :)